# php add method incorrectly working

Tags: php

I'm in the process of learning PHP and i'm having some trouble. My function is returning the "milestones" with the same date they were plugged in with. I believe I am using the add() method incorrectly. Thankyou.

PHPplayground: http://www.tehplayground.com/#cARB1wjth

```
$milestones = null;
$milestones = createMilestone($milestones, true, 10, "15-1-1", "birthday" );
var_dump( $milestones );

function createMilestone($milestones, $forward, $days, $startDate, $milestoneName ){
    if ( is_string($startDate)){
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $startDate );
    }else if(is_array($startDate) ){
        $date = $startDate["date"];
    }else{
        $date = $startDate;
    };

    $daysInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($days);
    if ($forward){
        $date->add($daysInterval);
    }else{
        $date->sub($daysInterval);
    }


    $milestones[$milestoneName]['date'] = $date;

    return $milestones;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to pass `$milestones` as an argument to your function.

Comment: Never mind. I don't think my comment is correct and the error is probably in some other part of your code. Can you post the sample output for your code ?

Comment: My bet is on this line: `$daysInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($days);`. You are clearly passing numeric value where string is expected. String with specific time format according to this: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: @Maximus2012 http://www.tehplayground.com/#cARB1wjth

Comment: Would you mind changing the line to `$daysInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('+' . $days . ' days');` and seeing what happens?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Thankyou. That corrected it: http://www.tehplayground.com/#iMVuZu2G8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use :

```
$daysInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($days . ' days');
```

See the doc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php) for DateInterval and that page for the diverse date formatting (called [relative format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)) you can use.

And BTW, if you give a DateTime like `"15-1-1"`, the correct format is not `"Y-m-d"` but `"y-m-d`" (lowercase '`y`')